# How to get a file from curled url

Tags: python, django, curl

I have the following curl, to pass a file to my url:

```
curl -F file=@/Users/david542/spreadsheet.xls  http://localhost:8000/spreadsheet
```

And in my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def wb_spreadsheet(request):
    # how do I get the file??
    return HttpResponse('Hello!')
```

How do I get the file object to process here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is passed in `request.FILES` --

```
@csrf_exempt
def wb_spreadsheet(request):
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    return HttpResponse('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) on *File Uploads*:

> When Django handles a file upload, the file data ends up placed in
>   request.FILES.

Use:

```
request.FILES['file']
```